Is there a way to change the division of a transform operation?
Sometimes when I'm trying to be precise with how I'm moving things, and I try to move some geometry by an exact amount I want to be able to also halve that transform. I've tried to use the / key after typing in the transform to divide it but that seems to only work for dividing by the value of the location or scale that the geometry is already at. Is there any way to quickly move geometry to the halfway point between a transform such as when snapping to a vertex?
Any way to make the 1 at the start of this into a 2?

Apologies if this a dumb question, I've tried checking on the blender forums and haven't been able to figure out if I'm missing something or not.

Pressing the / key only invokes the reciprocal function, i.e. whatever value you enter (and all that follow) will be used as divisor for 1.
So if you start off by entering 2 /, it switches to 1/2, and if you now additionally enter 5 for example because you want it to be 2/5, it becomes 1/25 instead.
If you want other values than 1 to be divided or even enter much more complex formulas, you can start the advanced mode by pressing = at first and then entering any formula you want in the same way you can enter them in other input fields in Blender.
Like for example if you want something to move by 5 m divided by the squareroot of 2 on the X axis, you can enter:
G X = 5/sqrt(2)

Ah! Thank you I had no idea about that advanced mode until now, really appreciate the help

@NascentSpace Actually I don't know if many people know about it, I usually never see it in tutorials or anything.
